# Choosing reactive web framework for Java

Tags: java, web, reactive-programming, vert.x, spring-webflux

1. Is it important for choosing correct framework that our application is absolutely stateless? We don't need to worry about synchronization, single thread model etc
2. I prefer a model where we write "regular" services layer. I mean that services are not aware about web framework and are synchronous. This approach simplifies development and testing of those services. And then "Controllers" layer calls those services in async way. Am I right when I want to achieve such architecture or it has some drawbacks?
3. I prefer that web framework will have a controller, which returns async result to the framework (like returning Futures in akka-http or Flux in Web Flux) instead of Vertx approach of handlers, because handlers take more code lines and are less readable. Am I right? Do i miss something?

If you thing that I'm right in 2. and 3. - which framework works in such way?

If you don't agree with 2. and 3. - which considerations should I take?

Answer (score 1):

I can't agree with 2 when it comes making service synchronous. I don't think you can make some parts synchronous, other parts asynchronous. Of course you can make it so, however, then you would lose all the good parts of reactive programming. If some part of the code is blocking, the other part is non-blocking, then non-blocking part will be blocked as well ;) 
Switching to reactive programming requires a different mindset and stuff, however, if you do it, then testing asynchronous services aren't that hard. I would say if you switch to reactive web framework ( web-flux), it is better to make each part of the code asynchronous.

Comment: Can you please explain a difference between:
1) My service is reactive and returns  a Future (in Vertx) or Mono (in WebFlux)
2) My service is synchronous , but I call it in a async way (like executeBlocking in Vertx)?

Comment: @PavelBernshtam, I think this video can help more. Async doesn't mean that it is a reactive. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=idApf9DMdfk